# Cannot read property 'state' of null

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have an input and a button

```
<input className="form-control" value={this.state.sentence} onChange={this.onChange}/>
<button type="button" onClick={this.handleSentence}></button>
```

I have binded both functions in constructor.

```
onChange(e) {this.setState({sentence: e.target.value});}

handleSentence(e) {console.log('string -->',this.state.sentence)}
```

on handleSentence function the `log` returns `Cannot read property 'state' of null`.

but in `render(let{sentence}=this.state)` returns the correct value and also I see what I type in input

***here is the constructor:***

```
class SentenceForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            sentence: '',
            splitedSentenceArray:[]
        }
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onClick = this.handleSentence.bind(this);
    }
```

Comment: This is null so I suppose you have not bound function to Component scope or you did it wrong. Paste whole component code please

Comment: @PiotrSołtysiak I did add the constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
<input className="form-control" value={this.state.sentence} onChange={this.onChange}/>
<button type="button" onClick={this.onClick}></button>
```

You bound `handleSentence` method to `this.onClick`. That was wrong.

Comment: aha, Thanks , it was making me crazy :D

Answer (score 4):

The best practise is to keep the function name same when you are binding. It avoids unnecessary confusion as in your case. You had done binding of `handleSentence` function by a different name but were still calling it by the same name so in your case the function was being called but since it was bound by a different name it did not refer to the correct context, where state is present.

```
class SentenceForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            sentence: '',
            splitedSentenceArray:[]
        }
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSentence = this.handleSentence.bind(this);
    }
```